# Embedding a custom Radar Chart into spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I don't see the Radar chart type in the Charts api, but can we link one designed with this tool - https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard up with data in a spreadsheet and embed it as well?  Is so, how would we go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get an image URL for the chart then you can embed it in a UiApp interface using `app.createImage()`.